# Print module download pdf file name change characters into HTML entities

Tags: 7

I am using print module to generate pdf using dompdf library. I am facing issue with file name which node title have ampersand(&) sign, this character is converting into `&amp;`.

For example- If file name is **hello & drupal** then the file name become `hello &amp; drupal - 2019-04-23`

My filename filename configuration is as attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not a specialist of dompdf, but having used fpdf, I think it's something you do in your print template or custom module that converts the fields in dompdf format. 
You may need to set a php rule like this:

```
$title = mb_convert_encoding($title, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384517/dompdf-character-encoding-utf-8

Or another one like this:

```
$titlePrintFriendly = preg_replace('#&amp;#',chr(38),$title);
```

and then print `$titlePrintFriendly`

I used the second one in the past to trick printing some special chars.
The dompdf library should be loaded in the file you add this line.

I took the char number from https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/lib/fonts/Symbol.afm

Answer (score 0):

A hook is available for this that is: Implements hook_print_pdf_filename_alter

```
/**
* Implements hook_print_pdf_filename_alter().
*/
function MY_MODULE_print_pdf_filename_alter(&$pdf_filename, &$path) {
  $pdf_filename = htmlspecialchars_decode($pdf_filename, ENT_NOQUOTES);
}
```